# Scipy distance: Computation between each index-matching observations of two 2D arrays

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, distance

I am trying to compute distance metrics between two 2D arrays, let's say A and B (n 'rows' x 6 'cols' each) using the `scipy.spatial.distance` functions. I would like to compute these distances between each pair of observations **that correspond to the same index** (e.g. between A[i,:] and B[i,:]) efficiently (i.e. without looping over the array index).

I know that `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` achieves this quickly, but between **all pairs** of observations, including those that not match in index. Therefore, I am looking for an quivalent but only for index-matching observations.

Here is an simple example for computing the euclidean distance:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance

a = np.array([[1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 9], [5, 7, 8, 6, 4, 1, 2]])
b = np.array([[9, 8, 9, 5, 7, 1, 2], [1, 5, 5, 7, 2, 1, 1]])

print(distance.cdist(a, b, 'euclidean')) # Compute the euclidean distance between each pair

for i in range(0, len(a), 1):
    print(distance.euclidean(a[i,:], b[i,:])) # Do the job but too long
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [numpy.linalg.norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) specifying the axis parameter:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 9], [5, 7, 8, 6, 4, 1, 2]])
b = np.array([[9, 8, 9, 5, 7, 1, 2], [1, 5, 5, 7, 2, 1, 1]])

print(np.linalg.norm(a-b, axis=1))
[13.11487705  5.91607978]
```

Comment: Thanks @FBruzzesi. This works perfect for "basic" distance metrics (euclidean, etc.), but what about other metrics like those provided by `scipy.spatial.distance`?

Comment: @G.L checking documentation you can see that you can specify the `ord` parameter for order of the norm. For other metrics you cannot use `np.linalg.norm`. If `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` is fast enough, you can retrieve the diagonal using `np.diag(distance.cdist(a, b, metric))`.